# Как правильно настроить VPN

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, администрирование, vpn, openvpn

Есть 2 подсети:

A: 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

B: 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

В подсети А установлен OpenVPN сервер с настройками 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0

К нему подключены клиенты 1-4. Клиент 4 находится физически совершенно в другой сети (у него 2 сетевые карты, одна wlan0 и другая tun0).

В подсети B есть компьютер 5, который не подключен к VPN и установить на него VPN не представляется возможным.

Необходимо, что бы компьтеры 1-3 могли видеть компьютер 5 и все его сервисы. Каким образом это можно организовать?

4 компьютер на Ubuntu, я верно понимаю, что нужно просто настроить сетевой мост между wlan0 и tun0 или этого будет мало?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Довольно тривиальное решение.

Подсеть В делаем 192.168.1.0/24, а на VPN сервере указываем маршруты, что на 192.168.1.0/24 идем через клиента 4

Вот соответствующая статья в документации https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

Отсносительно настройки ПК 4, рекомендую почитать статью http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/sharing_internet а именно раздел "Раздача Интернета в локальную сеть"

Comment: вот как раз основная проблема в том, что подсеть B я не могу изменять каким-либо образом, там находится только мое оборудование. Прочитал про ProxyARP но не могу понять как это правильно с OpenVPN реализовать.